# Restore Remote Git Branch from Local

Tags: git, git-branch

A *branch* on our *cloud repository* was **deleted**. I still have this *branch* in **my local git repository**. I want to *restore* this *branch* in the **cloud repository**.

Is this possible?

Comment: Push the branch.

Comment: It depends what you mean by restore. Is the branch in your local repository up to the same commit as the corresponding branch in the cloud repository?

Comment: The branch in the cloud repository matched what I have, but it was deleted.

Comment: Push the branch `git push origin <branch-name>`

Comment: Before I do that: a bit more poking around reveals that this branch was merged with the main branch in the cloud - but not in my local repo, where I haven't done a pull yet. If I push the unmerged branch from my repo, will it reappear in the cloud repo as a merged branch? Or will it reappear as a separate branch? I guess the former would be my hope, because the main branch now has those merged changes on it.

Answer (score 1):

Below command directly changes the remote branch you mentioned

```
git push -f origin <previous_commit>:<branch_name>
```

Locally try below command

```
git reset --hard <previous_commit>
```

And now push the changes to remote

Answer (score 0):

> If I push the unmerged branch from my repo, will it reappear in the cloud repo as a merged branch? Or will it reappear as a separate branch?

As a separate branch.
But the remote repository already has those commits (that you are pushing) through its merge commit: a merge commit has two parent, the second one being the branch being merged.
All you will be pushing will be the branch *name* on the last commit of that branch.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting a branch after it has been merged is *correct behavior*. You should not push and undo all of that. You should *fetch and prune*, and delete your local copy of the branch.